# Query which Find string and increment the count

Tags: mysql

I have table like that,

```
 id     name    count
 1      rrr     2   
 2      www     3   
 3      qqq     4   
 4      aaa     5   
 5      gyhhh   4   
 6      dfgdfg  5
```

I want to write the query which find the name in table and if it find then increment the count in count column for that name. The count maintain the no of time name used by the user.If user used the name , then I am check the name in db , if it found then I want to update row with increment in count.

Comment: You wouldn't normally store derived (or derivable) data

Comment: I not understand what you want to point out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `update` query required:

If you want to increase count only if the input parameter exactly matches the `name` then use this:

```
UPDATE your_table
SET `count` = `count` + 1
WHERE `name` = ?
```

And if you want to increase count if the input parameter is a substring of `name` then you can use `LIKE`

```
UPDATE your_table
SET `count` = `count` + 1
WHERE `name` LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')
```

**Note:** Replace the question mark (`?`) by your input parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select id,name, id + 1 from
(Select id,name from table_name where name in('sa','da','ba','ca')) as a;
```

hope it helps..

Comment: I think you have to increment the count +1 not the id